# How to type on:drop event in Svelte to access dataTransfer

Tags: typescript, svelte

I would like to correctly type the `on:drop` event with Svelte so I can access `dataTransfer`.

I've typed the event with the native `Event` but datatransfer is not present.

```html
<div on:drop={handleDrop}> dropzone </div>

<script lang="ts">
  function handleDrop(event: Event) {
    const files = event.dataTransfer.files
  }
</script>
```

This makes typescript throw an error:

> Property 'dataTransfer' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339)

How to properly type this kind of events ? I would preferably not cast anything

Comment: Shouldn't you use the correct event type: `DragEvent` instead of `Event`

Comment: Indeed, didn't know about that one, It's working as `dataTransfer` is available on `DragEvent`.  Should you write an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer) property is available only from some events. When listening on `drop` you should listen for [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent).

```html
<div on:drop={handleDrop}> dropzone </div>

<script lang="ts">
  function handleDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    const files = event.dataTransfer.files
  }
</script>
```